# CentOS: OpsCenter does not see other node's agent

Tags: centos, cassandra, agent, opscenter

I'm new with Apache Cassandra. I am trying to install a little sample cluster using two CentOS server. I followed the documentation (Tarball installation) and the nodes are up. However, when I go to OpsCenter, the nodes cannot see each other's agent (there is always "1 of 2 agents connected"..I tried to fix, but nothing change).

I tried both to disable and enable SSL, I tried to set the incoming_interface in opscenter.conf, I tried almost everything the network suggested to me, but the problem persisted.

Is there someone that could help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about your configuration, but experienced a similar use case myself, where the opscenter only had data from the local datastax agent.

My initial setup was: 3 cassandra nodes, all 3 running opscenter and datastax-agent, with the agent configured for the local node.
It seems that this was wrong, as the agents needed to be configured with (one?) opscenter address.  I decided to only run the agents in all 3 nodes, but opscenter only in one of them, and configured all 3 agents to point to that node (agent/bin/setup  ... this updates conf/address.yaml). 
This fixed my problem.  I still don't know how to setup opsCenter to more than one host, but that's a different problem.

Comment: Oh, thank you, thank you, thank you! You have solved my mistery! For the first time I see "All agents connected"...great return from holiday! Now, I try to think of a solution about this new problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend reviewing /var/lib/datastax-agent/conf/address.yaml on the nodes to validate that they both contain the hostname or ip address of the machine that is running opscenter in the "stomp_interface" setting.

Also, sometimes it is useful when initially configuring a cluster to restart both the agents and opscenter, and then to reload opscenter in your browser.

Comment: I tried all of these solutions, but nothing changed...